# SVG file: Delete every <text> object and contents w/ vim

Tags: xml, object, svg, vector, vim

I have an SVG file that contains thousands of objects, all of which are either `<text></text>` or `<path></path>` types.

**I need to delete every text-based object in the SVG/XML, removing both the tag AND the tags' respective contents.** File is *extremely* large, I'm looking for a single line solution.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/<text\(\n\|.\)\{-}<\/text>//g
:%s                                Substitute command, applied to every line.
   /                               Pattern begins after this character.
    <text                          Opening tag.
         \(\n\|.\)                 Matches carriage returns or any other character. 
                  \{-}             Matches previous atom zero or more times but as few as possible.
                      <\/text>     Closing tag.
                              //   Replace with nothing.
                                g  Apply substitution to every match on the line.
```

Comment: I would think that could leave behind empty <tspan> elements if there are any

Comment: I tried a few test files that included <tspan> elements and this substitution handled them all correctly. Do you have an example where it fails?